# Multitable queries jdo unowned relationships

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo, google-cloud-datastore, jdoql

I need some help

I'm working with gae, datastore and jdo

Country 1 - N department; Department 1 - N provinces, unowned relationship, as knowing country data at province

Entity Pais:

```
@PersistenceCapable(detachable = "true")
public class Pais implements Serializable{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4204342672595368670L;
    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent
    private String idPais;
    @Persistent
    private String codigo;
    @Persistent
    private String descripcion;
    @Persistent
    private Long version;
    @NotPersistent
    private String operacion;   
    @NotPersistent
    private String codePais;
```

Entity Departamento:

```
@PersistenceCapable(detachable = "true")
public class Departamento implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2029238048901900816L;
    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent
    private String idDepartamento;
    @Persistent
    private String codigo;
    @Persistent
    private String descripcion;
    @Persistent
    private Long version;
    @Persistent
    @Unowned
    private Pais beanPais;
    @Persistent
    private String codePais;
    @NotPersistent
    private String operacion;
    @NotPersistent
    private String codeDepartamento;
```

Entity Provincia

```
@PersistenceCapable(detachable = "true")
public class Provincia implements Serializable{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2560617366920790922L;
    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent
    private String idProvincia;
    @Persistent
    private String codigo;
    @Persistent
    private String descripcion;
    @Persistent
    private Long version;
    @NotPersistent
    private String operacion;
    @NotPersistent
    private String codeProvincia;
    @Persistent
    private String codeDepartamento;
    @Persistent
    @Unowned
    private Departamento beanDepartamento;
    @NotPersistent
    private String codePais;
```

query that allows me to meet country data, accessed district
JDO

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: query that allows me to meet country data, accessed district, using JDOQL

Comment: I'm sorry, I do not understand how that is a question.  Please be more specific.  If you are having trouble with English, please use the language you speak best -- someone here will understand you.